# MySQL: Prevent duplicate rows when email message has multiple attachments

Tags: mysql, duplicates

Here is my MySQL query for displaying the emails in a folder (slimmed down of course)...

```
SELECT em.id
FROM email_messages AS em 
LEFT JOIN email_attachments AS ea on ea.id_email=em.id 
WHERE em.id='4'
```

The problem is that if an email has multiple attachments the same email will appear twice, such as the `email_message` with the `id` 4.

Without changing the structure of the SQL tables how can I return any value (such as 1) to represent that the email has an attachment without returning duplicate rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `DISTINCT` to get only unique values,

```
SELECT DISTINCT em.id
FROM   email_messages AS em 
       LEFT JOIN email_attachments AS ea 
          ON ea.id_email = em.id 
WHERE  em.id = '4'
```

or a `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT em.id
FROM   email_messages AS em 
       LEFT JOIN email_attachments AS ea 
          ON ea.id_email = em.id 
WHERE  em.id = '4'
GROUP  BY em.id
```